# MySQL - Join two rows to two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: `user` and `photo`. They look like this:

[image: Database tables]

I need to perform a SELECT on the `user` table based on `uuid`, returning the `url` for both `profile_photo` and `background_photo`, if they exist.

These are essentially the final fields I need (the last two being JOINed from `photo`):

`user.name`, `user.profile_photo_url`, `user.background_photo_url`

WHERE `user.uuid` = SOME_UUID

Can somebody point me in the right direction with this statement?

Comment: Could you show us some data and what you need from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT user.name, photo_a.url AS profile_photo_url, photo_b.url as background_photo_url FROM user LEFT JOIN photo as photo_a ON user.profile_photo_uuid = photo_a.uuid LEFT JOIN photo as photo_b ON user.background_photo_uuid = photo_b.uuid WHERE user.uuid = SOME_ID
```

Comment: This also works great, after altering `background_photo_uuid` to `background_photo_url`. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. My mistake. Corrected my answer.

Comment: This is similar to Dylan Su's answer, but I'm curious which is "better" from a performance perspective. Any ideas?

Comment: Both answers are same except, for Dylan Su's answer, it will not return any user which has not either of the photo columns' entry in "photo" table. In my case, it will return each user with NULL values for photo URLs field, if their entries do not exist in "photo" table.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
SELECT u.name,u.profile_photo_uuid,u.background_photo_url FROM user u, photo p 
WHERE u.uuid = **userid** AND 
( p.uuid = u.profile_photo_uuid  OR p.uuid = u.background_photo_url);
```